# Remove duplicate labels with symbolic y coords

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, nodes-near-coords

I am new to pgfplots and have a problem with the following example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[title  = Some fancy benchmark data,
    xbar,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
    enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
    symbolic y coords = {Intel Xeon E5630,AMD Turion II Neo N54L,Intel i7 3632QM},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=7}
  ]
  \addplot coordinates { (0.155,AMD Turion II Neo N54L)         (0.087,Intel i7 3632QM)
                         (0.134,Intel Xeon E5630)  };
  \addplot coordinates { (0.078,AMD Turion II Neo N54L)         (0.047,Intel i7 3632QM)
                         (0.069,Intel Xeon E5630)    };
  \legend{prod1, prod2}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Looks ok, except that there are duplicate labels on the y axis.
[image: result of the tikz code with marked problems]

How can I remove the labels I marked with red?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)).

Comment: You could remove the double entries e.g. by adding `ytick distance=1` to the `axis` environment options.

Comment: Great to here. Shall I write an answer or shall we close this question as "solved in the comments"?

Comment: If you write a answer with the solution I'll accept it, thanks.

Comment: Alternatively, `ytick=data`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., you are right, that works in this case, because in the first `\addplot` command all symbolic coords are given. But this is not a general solution ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I already stated in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386298/r#comment957282_386298) you can e.g. remove the double yticks and the corresponding labels by adding `ytick distance=1` to the `axis` environment options.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title=Some fancy benchmark data,
        xbar,
        y axis line style={
            draw=none,          % (<-- changed)
        },
        axis x line=none,
        tickwidth=0pt,
        enlarge y limits=0.2,
        enlarge x limits=0.02,
        symbolic y coords={
            Intel Xeon E5630,
            AMD Turion II Neo N54L,
            Intel i7 3632QM%
        },
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords style={
            /pgf/number format/precision=4,
        },
        ytick distance=1,       % <-- added
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {
            (0.155,AMD Turion II Neo N54L)
            (0.087,Intel i7 3632QM)
            (0.134,Intel Xeon E5630)
        };
        \addplot coordinates {
            (0.078,AMD Turion II Neo N54L)
            (0.047,Intel i7 3632QM)
            (0.069,Intel Xeon E5630)
        };
        \legend{
            prod1,
            prod2,
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]